# MYSQL: Select changed row where

Tags: mysql, sql

1 -

```
create table changes(snapdate date,value int, uid int); 
insert into changes values 
('2013-04-22', 0, 1 ), 
('2013-04-21', 1,1 ), 
('2013-04-20', 1,1 ), 
('2013-04-19', 1,1 ), 
('2013-04-19', 0,2 ), 
('2013-04-19', 1,1 ), 
('2013-04-18', 0,1 ), 
('2013-04-17', 0,1 ), 
('2013-04-17', 1,2 ), 
('2013-04-16', 1,1 ), 
('2013-04-16', 0 ,2);
```

2 -

```
SELECT a.snapdate, a.value 
FROM ( 
  SELECT t1.*, COUNT(*) AS rank 
  FROM changes t1
  LEFT JOIN changes t2 ON t1.snapdate >= t2.snapdate 
  GROUP BY t1.snapdate 
) AS a 
LEFT JOIN ( 
  SELECT t1.*, COUNT(*) AS rank 
  FROM changes t1
  LEFT JOIN changes t2 ON t1.snapdate >= t2.snapdate 
  GROUP BY t1.snapdate 
) AS b ON a.rank = b.rank+1 AND a.value = b.value 
WHERE b.snapdate IS NULL
ORDER BY a.snapdate DESC;
```

Works fine but how to select `WHERE uid=2` for example ?
I can't use temporary table :

```
 create temporary table changes_temp
    as
    select *
    from changes
    where uid = 2
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the WHERE clause in your subquery

```
    SELECT a.snapdate, a.value 
FROM ( 
  SELECT t1.*, COUNT(*) AS rank 
  FROM changes t1
  LEFT JOIN changes t2 ON t1.snapdate >= t2.snapdate 
  WHERE t2.uid=t1.uid AND t2.uid=2
  GROUP BY t1.snapdate 
) AS a 
LEFT JOIN ( 
  SELECT t1.*, COUNT(*) AS rank 
  FROM changes t1
  LEFT JOIN changes t2 ON t1.snapdate >= t2.snapdate 
  WHERE t2.uid=t1.uid AND t2.uid=2
  GROUP BY t1.snapdate 
) AS b ON a.rank = b.rank+1 AND a.value = b.value 
WHERE b.snapdate IS NULL
ORDER BY a.snapdate DESC;
```

Created [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3910/12) for testing.
Is that what you want ? You didn't explained the goal of your query

Answer (score 0):

Add a where clause :

```
SELECT a.snapdate, a.value 
FROM ( 
  SELECT t1.*, COUNT(*) AS rank 
  FROM changes t1
  LEFT JOIN changes t2 ON t1.snapdate >= t2.snapdate 
  WHERE t1.uid = 2
  GROUP BY t1.snapdate 
) AS a 
LEFT JOIN ( 
  SELECT t1.*, COUNT(*) AS rank 
  FROM changes t1
  LEFT JOIN changes t2 ON t1.snapdate >= t2.snapdate 
  WHERE t1.uid = 2
  GROUP BY t1.snapdate 
) AS b ON a.rank = b.rank+1 AND a.value = b.value 
WHERE b.snapdate IS NULL
ORDER BY a.snapdate DESC;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3910/14)